# Reading data from file with different number of components in each line in Python

Tags: python, readfile

In this project I need to read the input file with unknown data and put it in a dictionary. The first column will always be name, while the rest will always be values. However, we don't know have many column for the values can it contain. For example:

```
name1;1;2;3;4
name2;1;1;1
name3;5;6
name4;9
```

I was thinking using split(';') but each row might have different columns.

```
for line in file:
   line = line.rstrip()
   name, value = line.split(';')
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Wanted final result:

```
d={name1:[1,2,3,4], name2:[1,1,1], name3:[5,6], name4:[9]}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried your idea? What result did you get? How was it different than what you want?

Comment: @CrazyChucky: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I don't know the *data would make it work.
Before that I was only using name,data=line.split(';'), therefore it gave out ValueError: too many values to unpack. Anyways thanks to you it's working now!

Comment: Sure thing. For future reference, that sort of information is a good thing to include in your question. (In fact it wouldn't be a bad idea to edit it into this question, to make it more useful for others if they come across it.)

Comment: That was a good edit, except don't add answers to your question. That's what answers are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! Splitting your line and using multiple assignment is the right idea. The missing piece is that you can use `*` in multiple assignment to make one portion have a variable length. Check out [this article](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/) for an excellent rundown of various uses and idioms.

```py
result = {}

with open('name_of_your_file') as file:
    for line in file:
        # Set name to the first element, and set value to the rest.
        name, *value = line.rstrip().split(';')
        result[name] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `split(';')` is a good idea here, this should work for you:

```
filename = 'path_to_your_file'
res={}
with open(filename, 'r') as file: #opens your file in reading mode
    for line in file: #reads the file line by line
        temp = line.rstrip('\n') #removes ending newline characters
        temp = temp.split(';') #split string by ';' into a list
        res[temp.pop(0)]=temp #uses the first element of the list as dictionary key, and the rest of the list as value
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading lines into the list you can use dict comprehension to do this -

reading all lines into list -

```
list1 = ['name1;1;2;3;4',
'name2;1;1;1',
'name3;5;6',
'name4;9']
```

using dict comprehension -

```
result_dict  ={item.split(';')[0]: item.split(';')[1:] for item in list1}
print(result_dict)
```

**output -**

```
{'name1': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
 'name2': ['1', '1', '1'],
 'name3': ['5', '6'],
 'name4': ['9']}
```